# Run Future in sync in Flutter or Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am kind of new to dart and flutter.
I wanted to know how would someone run a Future synchronously?
Is it possible at all?

Comment: Maybe what you meant is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940412/how-to-invoke-async-function-in-sync-function-in-flutter/73653640#73653640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. If it was, then you would be able to freeze the UI thread until that Future is complete.

Comment: After digging up more documents and actually finishing an application I kind of get how Future's work. They are equivalent to JavaScript's Promise, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, they are exactly like JavaScript promises! I have a couple of talks about it, might help understand things https://youtu.be/p8dY_tsAbx8?t=3976 https://youtu.be/vPHxckiSmKY?t=2213